# Java-Oracle Fuzzy Search

Tags: java, sql, oracle, oracle10g, fuzzy-search

We would like to have a more "fuzzy" approach:

Example, if we enter

Travel Sky

RapidInsight

Wal mart

The database should be able to retrieve the following:

TravelSky Technology

Rapid Insight

Wal-mart

This is how google works.

I have tried a lot with my own logics like `regex` etc.. But worked nothing.

currently in our application we are searching based on exact maching....but now we wan it more fuzzy lets say if i have some full company name in my database

For ex.

TravelSky Technology

then if i search 'travel sky' then it should return  TravelSky and so on. currently we are having exact maching.

let me know if more examples required.

I found CONTAINS in oracle 10g which oracle doc mentioned that perform this kind of search. still i am trying it..

Comment: A more fuzzy approach to what? Can you provide examples of what you made so far?

Comment: What is your question. You've made a number of statements. Are you having difficulty implementing something? What is the problem? If you're looking for recommendations then this is off-topic on the entire network.

Comment: Fuzzy-search is a vast and complex subject. You will not build google in a day :) However, there are standard tools that you can use to help you. You should start with the [Oracle Text documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/text.112/e24435/toc.htm).

Answer (score 2):

You didn't give details on how the fuzzy search was to be used.  For an alternative to Oracle Text, you might consider using apache [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/)(lucene).  It has full text search, faceting, clustering, geospatial search, and from my experience is very scalable. If using from a front end, it also has REST api that is handy.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the **Oracle Text** package which is designed specifically for your issue.  I would hesitate to build this functionality on my own, when I have already paid top dollar for an Oracle Database.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/text.920/a96517/cdefault.htm